# jquery / jquery ui : $ is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a file that i think is jQuery UI. It mentions jQuery in the code but it is condensed, so it's hard to tell.

I included both jquery1.6.2.js and custom.js. (confirmed that they are both loading properly)

There is a sliding image panel that works fine when both are included, although I do get the message:
$ is undefined
from my own code (not the custom.js)

I read somewhere that the problem might be that I need to not include jQuery, but that seems to disable the image slider. The $ function seems to work fine if I remove the custom.js, but then of course the slide doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe this is an old build of jquery UI and i need to update it? but i can't see how to tell which features i should add

Comment: My ESP is on the fritz today, so I'm going to have to ask you to present a testcase.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your loading the jQuery library before you load any other JavaScript that relies on the jQuery library.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to include jQuery *then* jQueryUI **before** any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load jQuery before things that depend upon it
2. Make sure jQuery is bound to `window.$` (might not be with `noConflict`)

From the statement:

> > the $ function seems to work fine if i *remove* the custom.js

Then I believe that *either* `custom.js` is loaded before jQuery *or* the problem lies in `custom.js`: in particular, it is likely muddling with `window.$` -- through `jQuery.noConflict` or otherwise. However, a test-case is required to say more with confidence.

Happy coding.